# htaccess smart url for listing directories

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, coding-style

1> This is the htaccess rule to display a smart URL for the path /uploadr/public folder !!

/uploadr/public folder is the one to list the directories and does not contain any html documents or such

```
  RewriteRule ^Uploadr-Public$ /uploadr/public [L]
```

However when i access http://localhost/Uploadr-Public in the url the path 
mapping works fine but does not display the smart URL (Uploadr-Public)

How can is solve this ?

Heres the screenshot of what it is currently displaying in url!!

[image]

2> Also if suppose one wants to access a folder named temp which is in

```
 /var/www/html/uploadr/public/temp
```

can he specify the path in url as

```
            htttp://localhost/Uploadr-Public/temp
```

where Uploadr-Public/ is smart URL and temp is a folder inside public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that `/uploadr/public` points to a physical directory and you're not using trailing slash in rewritten path. `mod_dir` module that runs after `mod_rewrite` adds a trailing slash in front of directories.

You can use this rule to fix it:

```
RewriteRule ^Uploadr-Public/(.*)$ /uploadr/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear browser cache before testing it.

Comment: Works fine !!! and what if i wanna add the foldername to url in browser !!! Ex  http://localhost/Uploadr-Public/foldername

Comment: What should `/Uploadr-Public/foldername` be rewritten to?

Comment: i mean not in htaccess !! Suppose one wants to access a folder named temp as in  /uploadr/public/temp  can he specify the path in url as  htttp://localhost/Uploadr-Public/temp where Uploadr-Public/ is smart URL

Comment: What does that mean? What URL did you enter and what is the problem?

Comment: sorry made a mistake !! That works fine !! Thanku sooo much!